# Can a universal indicator turn colorless?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, ph

I learned that litmus paper could be bleached by chlorine to turn colorless. I’m wondering if any chemical substances can react with all the components of a universal indicator such that it turns colorless, or stops being a pH indicator?

Comment: I would suspect the same chlorine bleach.  Universal indicator consists of organic dyes.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi really? I heard that chlorine just turns it purple or red

Comment: A fun demo is to make red cabbage soup, which goes from deep red at very low pH to deep violet at high pH, and then add a bit of chlorine bleach to turn it clear.